# Using animateWithDuration to animate two views at the same speed

Tags: ios

I have two UIViews that I want to move at the same speed and at the same time.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^ {
    myView1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, myView1.frame.size.height - 50.0);
    myView2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, myView1.frame.size.height - 100.0);
 }];
```

However, doing the above means `myView2` animates at a speed that is twice as fast as `myView1`.

How can I get both views to animate at the same but at the same speed (so that one finishes first, followed by the other, but they start animating at the same time)?

Comment: Have you noticed that you are assigning height of view1 to view2 in 2 instruction in the block, and btw if both the views are of same size the second view will be going on double speed as it has to minimize the height almost double than view1

Comment: So is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start them at the same time and give the animation that needs to travel twice as far twice as much time to do so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^ {
    myView1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, myView1.frame.size.height - 100.0);
}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
    myView2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, myView1.frame.size.height - 50.0);
}];
```

Basic velocity math.

---

An alternate approach:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    myView1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, myView1.frame.size.height - 50.0);
    myView2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, myView1.frame.size.height - 50.0);
}
                                  completion:^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        myView2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, myView1.frame.size.height - 50.0);
    }];
}];
```

---

I'm not sure which method is better or would be preferred.

The first approach uses two separate calls to `animateWithDuration`, one for each view, with one animating twice the distance in twice the time (so the same velocity overall).

The second approach uses a nested call  to `animateWithDuration` via a `completion` block.  First, both views are animated to the same size at the same speed.  Next, the view that needs to go twice the distance is animated for the remaining distance (at the same velocity).